# [LXD]Lvm thin snapshot shipping support for lvm storagepool move

Tags: lxd

As i understand with Zfs lxd storagepool  move is fast ( as no rsync is involved) as things can be moved from different Zfs Storage pools via snapshot diff.

However no clarity is there for lvm thin snapshot shipping i.e using https://github.com/LINBIT/thin-send-recv  OR a slower rsync shall be used(In scenerio where both side pools is lvm thin only)

Answer (score 0):

Answered in this link by the LXD team:

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/lxd-lvm-thin-snapshot-shipping-support-for-lvm-storagepool-move/37467

> It uses raw block transfer in this case.As i understand with Zfs lxd
> storagepool move is fast ( as no rsync is involved) as things can be
> moved from different Zfs Storage pools via snapshot diff.
>
> However no clarity is there for lvm thin snapshot shipping i.e using
> https://github.com/LINBIT/thin-send-recv OR a slower rsync shall be
> used(In scenerio where both side pools is lvm thin only)

---

> It uses rsync for filesystem volumes and direct block copy for block volumes. We have a features matrix which shows which storage drivers support optimized volume transfer: https://documentation.ubuntu.com/lxd/en/latest/reference/storage_drivers/#feature-comparison